# How to make this into a OR statement for searching by two columns of info?

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio

```
Private Sub SearchBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles SearchBox.TextChanged
    'Filter for searching by lastname
    PersonsBindingSource1.Filter = String.Format("LastName Like '{0}%'", SearchBox.Text)
End Sub
```

Currently this code is from a textbox that I am using to search by LastName in a table containing FirstName, LastName, and StoreNumber. It works like I want, ex. being that when you type in the search box it auto filters the data down to show which row contains that last name or letters containing that last name.

I want it to be able to search by FirstName OR LastName, is this possible with the current setup? I haven't been able to figure out the syntax for BindingSource.Filter OR statements.

Answer (score 0):

```
PersonsBindingSource1.Filter = String.Format("LastName Like '{0}%' OR FirstName Like '{0}%'", SearchBox.Text)
```

Just needed to change the syntax like that. I was trying to do

```
("FirstName OR LastName Like '{0}%'", SearchBox.Text)
```

which obviously did not work.